# Graph of Ac across pure resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

[image: Graph]

This the graph of AC across a pure resistance.

Can anybody tell me why $I_{max}$ >$V_{max}$ ?

According to me $I=\frac{V}{R}$  therefore whatever maybe the voltage I should be less than V by a factor of R.

Thus shouldn't the I and $V_{r}$ switch position( I should take's $V_{r}$ position and $V_{r}$ should take I position) ?

**Here I denotes Current and $V_{r}$ denotes  Voltage**

Comment: What if R<1? Then I>V.

Comment: Is 10 m more or less than 15 kg? How about 10000 mm and 15 kg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the curve plotted above is valid for a specific case as $$I>R \implies R<1$$ If $R>1$ then the curve would be same as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you cannot directly compare $I$ and $V$, because they are quantities of different dimensions, and thus are measured in different units, so it is not meaningful to say $I_{max}>V_{max}$. Since they are measured in different units, their numerical values depend on the choice of units, so it matters whether $I$ is measured in amperes or milliamperes.

In order to compare $I$ and $V$, you need to express them in the same units. This is where Ohm's Law comes in. Because $\frac{V}{R}$ has the same dimension as $I$, it can be expressed in the same units, allowing for meaningful comparisons to be made, where in this case, $I = \frac{V}{R}$.